# Is it possible to specify a variable value as length parameter in SUBSTR function DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I have the below fields in DB2. My task here is to get the first 5 characters from Full name and put the value in First name and the remaining in last name.

I tried to use SUBSTR(FULLNAME, 1,LENGTH) it gives me an error saying that argument 3 is not valid, I believe we can't use another variable value for argument 3. Please do let me know if there is any other way to achieve this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GmlR.jpg)

Thanks

Comment: What is `length`?  The syntax is fine.

Comment: length is another column in my table, I have added an image, please have a look at it

Comment: I actually found a way to get the value

 select                            
substr(fullname,1,(length(digits(mylen))-3)+digits(mylen))

Answer (score 0):

try Something like this :

```
select left(fullname, mylen) from yourtable
```